# Reading geojson into Leaflet results in error?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, json, ajax

I'm trying to read a geojson file into leaflet. Everything works out when I copy the text from the geojson file and paste it into

```
var data = { }
```

So I think the file should be ok for leaflet. But I rather want to be able to read the actual file. Right now I keep all files locally on my hard drive. I loaded Ajax and tried to read the file by

```
var data = L.GeoJSON.AJAX("data.json")
```

If I open the HTML the map loads, but not the point markers of the geojson file. When I use the Firefox Console I get:

```
TypeError: this.callInitHooks is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should be `L.geoJSON` or `new L.GeoJSON`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it didn't solve my problem. If I use `L.geoJSON` I get the same error, with `new L.geoJSON` I get `Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.`, which doesn't make sense, since it works when I use the same data and `var data = L.GeoJSON.AJAX("data.json")`

Comment: Sorry, I was not mindful enough when answering. If you are using leaflet-ajax plugin, it should definitely be `var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("geojson.json");` or `var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson.ajax("data.json");`
. See https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax

Comment: @TomazicM: you should turn your comment into a proper answer.

Comment: with both I get `Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself after reading [this](https://medium.com/@maptastik/loading-external-geojson-a-nother-way-to-do-it-with-jquery-c72ae3b41c01)

Apparently, just reading a GeoJSON file is not working, since you need the "response" of it:

```
L.geoJSON(data.responseJSON)
```